# How to use manage Identity to connect to azure storage from a pod in aks cluster

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-managed-identity

I have a managed Identity created. my application uses using flask.
Now my pods are deployed in the AKS cluster. my pod needs to connect to Azure storage using the pip package azure-storage-file-share.
How can I manage identity to access Azure storage from the pod?

I think I have to bind the managed Identity to the pod first.
What has to be done at the application level?

locally I was able to connect to Azure storage using the access key but not from the pod in aks cluster.

Comment: you need workload identity configured on your cluster: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/workload-identity-overview?tabs=dotnet

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Managed Identity to connect to Azure Storage, you need to make sure that your cluster is configured to use Managed Identity and linked to your storage account.

```
az aks create --resource-group <resource-group-name> --name <aks-cluster-name> --enable-managed-identity
```

[image]

create/verify your Azure Storage account so that it is configured to allow access from the Managed Identity associated with your AKS cluster.

```
az role assignment create --assignee <managed-identity-object-id> --role "Storage Blob Data Contributor" --scope /subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<resource-group-name>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<storage-account-name>
```

[image]
[image]

Now for the the flask app section, usually all the latest version of the Azure SDK for Python supports Managed Identity. In your Flask application, use the `DefaultAzureCredential` from the `azure.identity` library to automatically authenticate with Managed Identity.
just replace `<your-storage-account-name>` with the name of your Azure Storage account as below
Example :

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

from azure.storage.fileshare import ShareServiceClient

from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

  

app = Flask(__name__)

  

def get_storage_client():

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

account_url = "https://asenstoracc1711.file.core.windows.net"

return ShareServiceClient(account_url=account_url, credential=credential)
```

Your Flask application should be able to access Azure Storage using Managed Identity.

Reference documents:

[Managed Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-managed-identity)

[Access Azure storage using azure library for python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/sdk/examples/azure-sdk-example-storage-use?tabs=cmd)\

[AKS Managed Pod Identity and access to Azure Storage](https://blog.baeke.info/2019/02/02/aks-managed-pod-identity-and-access-to-azure-storage/)

Comment: So I did go over azure-identity and I tried to run locally. 
Shouldnt DefaultAzureCredential() pick up my env variables? And what should be the content of env variables, I thought access_key would be enough. Could you please share this detail.

Comment: could you help me understand this?

Comment: @tigert DefaultAzureCredential() will try to check Azure CLI login locally if you have logged in with the user locally, it will pick that user or service principal login by default.

Comment: If you have deployed a Flask app in your AKS, enabled managed identity and assigned it the role on Storage account > the DefaultAzureCredential() will search for existing authentication, as you cannot run az login in AKS manually, It will automatically pick Managed Identity Credentials and search if there's any managed Identity enabled on the cluster and authenticate accordingly. Make sure you have Enabled managed identity on AKS and using the same managed identity Client ID in the environment variables of your Flask app and run it inside your pod.

Comment: the aks managed identity is different form identity assigned at the pod level. This won't work. it needs workload identity enabled

Comment: @Thomas so my goal is to use package azure-identity so that the pod can access azure storage account when deployed in aks. What are the roles that the UAMI needs in order to do that?

Comment: did you enable / configured workload identity on your cluster ?

Comment: @Thomas How do I do that?
Also, do I need any change in my application code or it will pick up MI?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/workload-identity-overview?tabs=dotnet

Comment: if you use latest azure.identity package with DefaultAzureCredential, that should work